# windows schedule command to run regularly

Tags: windows, windows-8, automation, scheduled-tasks

I apologize if this has been covered elsewhere or even in the MS docs, but I haven't found my answer yet.

I have a program on my PATH, lets call it `myprog.exe`.

All I want to do is configure my Windows 8 (not 8.1) machine (it happens to be a laptop) to execute this program every 4 hours, without question. Conveniently, logging the output to one file would be a bonus but is not necessary. Logging the output is not coded into the program.

If this were a linux machine, I could simply make a crontab entry to run this every 4 hours. I simply want to do the same thing on windows. I want the program to run even if I am not signed in, but if my laptop is on. I do NOT need to queue multiple executions if my laptop is off for a while.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: You are looking for the Task Scheduler http://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-create-task-basic-task-wizard

Comment: thanks. I've been searching, but maybe I need a tutorial on Task Scheduler?

Comment: There is not very much to know. You simply can choose there a programm to start and configure when it should run. Its very basic and all using the GUI. If you stuck somewhere just ask specific and you may get help.Edit: Ahh, i see you need logging as well... Then this might be not the thing you are looking for.

Comment: where im lost is how to schedule for every 4 hours given the options in task scheduler which start at "daily"

Comment: You need to create an advaced task not the simple one with the wizzard. There you are able to define a trigger. At the advanced trigger options you will find "repeat every xy hour"

Comment: thanks for your help. I can't seem to find this option in task scheduler but I am looking and reading more resources. I'm probably just doing something dumb here...

Comment: specifically I have not yet found the "repeat every x hour" option, but I keep looking for it

Comment: Take a look through this TechNet page: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721871.aspx It should give you enough to create your task.

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't comment I might as well answer this.

Firstly, as others have commented, Task Scheduler is the standard Windows application that runs scheduled tasks.  This http://www.howtogeek.com/school/using-windows-admin-tools-like-a-pro/lesson2/all/ is a detailed tutorial that should get you up and running.

In terms of logging one approach is to run a script that will redirect the output of the program to a file.  This https://superuser.com/a/758712/382867 question has a good answer by Kevin Fegan that covers the basics of doing this with batch scripts.  Once you've got a batch script working that does the logging as your program runs you can schedule that script.

It might take some work to get going but if you hit a problem come back here with a specific question.