# How to do logging after taking admission access in batch script?

Tags: batch, batch-file, script, logging

I have typed the suggested solution in ***[Log an entire batch file output](https://superuser.com/questions/698496/log-an-entire-batch-file-output)***.

But only work when we batch script doesn't ask for admin access or take any user input.

In my script i I'm take the administrative access and also have user input:

```bat
@echo off
:: BatchGotAdmin
::-------------------------------------
REM  --> Check for permissions
>nul 2>&1 "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\cacls.exe" "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\config\system"

REM --> If error flag set, we do not have admin.
if '%errorlevel%' NEQ '0' (
    echo Requesting administrative privileges...
    goto UACPrompt
) else ( goto gotAdmin )

:UACPrompt
    echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    set params = %*:"="
    echo UAC.ShellExecute "cmd.exe", "/c %~s0 %params%", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"

    "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    exit /B

:gotAdmin
    pushd "%CD%"
    CD /D "%~dp0"
::--------------------------------------
set LOGFILE=batch.log
call :LOG > %LOGFILE%
exit /B
:LOG
REM Set IP address to USB Ethernet
echo "Set IP address to USB Ethernet :"
set /p SystemIP="Enter the System IP address[127.*.*.*]:" 
set /p  SystemSubnetMask="Enter the System Subnetmark[Default:255.255.255.0]:" 
IF [%system_subnetmask%]==[] set /p system_subnetmask=255.255.255.0
set /p SystemGateway="Enter the System Default Gateway[127.*.*.*]:" 
echo "Aviliable Ethernet Interface :"
netsh interface show interface
set /p EthernetInterfaceName="Type the Ethernet Interface Name:" 
netsh interface ip set address %EthernetInterfaceName% static %SystemIP% %SystemSubnetMask% %SystemGateway%
netsh interface ip set dns %EthernetInterfaceName% static 8.8.8.8
netsh interface ip add dnsserver %EthernetInterfaceName% address=4.2.2.2 index=1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *"How to do logging after taking admission access in batch script?"*
>
> - **The ***[link](https://superuser.com/questions/698496/log-an-entire-batch-file-output)*** in your question answers this in a wide variety of ways.**
>
> *"I have typed the suggested solution in below link but only work when we batch script doesn't ask for admin access...*
>
> - **Some changes/edit in your code are necessary, including those that make use of **[vbs](/questions/tagged/vbs)**, and that interfere with the mechanic of requesting administrator rights."**
>
> *"... or take any user input."*
>
> - **These actions in your code, which will receive inputs, are after the action of obtaining administrator rights (by VBS), so if the previous one does not occur, this one does not occur either.**

---

Without going into much detail, your objective focuses on obtaining the logs of the executions of your commands listed in batch, but in trying this, you are omitting the outputs from the screen because you use the redirection to a log file, however, without realizing that the screen (stdout) will not have any command outputs, it will even paralyze and wait for `set /p` command inputs.

This doesn't exactly break your running code, but it certainly "hangs" without displaying any message on the screen, and it stays there waiting for user/admin interaction to continue, which never happens.

---

What I suggest then would be changes where the actions needed for registration were divided from the actions needed to receive interaction/input:

```bat
@echo off

>nul 2>&1 "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\cacls.exe" "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\config\system" && goto :gotAdmin

echo/Requesting administrative privileges... & goto :UACPrompt
 
:UACPrompt 
set "_params=" & if not "%*" == "" =;(
     set "_params=%*" 
     call set "_params=%%_params:"=%%"
    );=
    
> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" =;(
     echo/Set UAC = CreateObject("Shell.Application"^)
     echo/UAC.ShellExecute "%ComSpec%", "/c %~s0 %_params%", "", "runas", 1
    );= && "C:\Windows\System32\cscript.exe" //Nologo "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" 

>nul 2>&1 del /q "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" & exit /b || goto :eOf

:gotAdmin
cd /d "%~dp0"
set "_LogFile=%temp%\batch.log"

echo/Set IP address to USB Ethernet : 
set /p "_SystemIP=Enter the System IP address [127.*.*.*]: " 
set /p "_SystemSubnetMask=Enter the System Subnet Mask [Default: 255.255.255.0]: "

if "%_SystemSubnetMask%" == "" set "_System_SubnetMask=255.255.255.0"
set /p "_SystemGateway=Enter the System Default Gateway [127.*.*.*]: " 

echo/Aviliable Ethernet Interface:
"C:\Windows\System32\netsh.exe" interface show interface | findstr .

set /p "_EthernetInterfaceName=Type the Ethernet Interface Name: " 

:: logging commands after defined in/with admin inputs
:: ----------------------------------------------------
for %%i in (EthernetInterfaceName,SystemIP, SystemSubnetMask, SystemGateway
    )do "%ComSpec%" /v:on /e:on /c "echo/%%~i: !_%%~i!"

2>&1 =;(
      netsh interface show interface | findstr .
      for %%i in (EthernetInterfaceName,SystemIP, SystemSubnetMask, SystemGateway)do "%ComSpec%" /v:on /e:on /c "echo/%%~i: !_%%~i!"
      echo\ "C:\Windows\System32\netsh.exe" interface ip set address %_EthernetInterfaceName% static %_SystemIP% %_SystemSubnetMask% %_SystemGateway%
      echo\ "C:\Windows\System32\netsh.exe" interface ip set dns %_EthernetInterfaceName% static 8.8.8.8
      echo\ "C:\Windows\System32\netsh.exe" interface ip add dnsserver %_EthernetInterfaceName% address=4.2.2.2 index=1
      echo\ "C:\Windows\System32\ipconfig.exe" /flushdns
     );= >"%_LogFile%"

type "%_LogFile%" | clip 
"C:\Windows\System32\timeout.exe" -1
```

---

## - Why?

Although it is possible to redirect **`stderr`** to **`stdout`**, it is also possible to redirect **`stderr`** and **`stdout`** simultaneously, what is not possible is
redirect **`stdin`** (**`set /P`)** to **`stdout`** to a file and simultaneously have **`stdout`** on screen receiving **`stdin`**. And your question points to that goal.

---

## Pointer   Stream

***[The stdin, stdout, and stderr global constant pointers are standard streams for input, output, and error output](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/stdin-stdout-stderr?view=msvc-170)***

```bat
stdin  Standard input     
stderr Standard error 
stdout Standard output

Redirection:
stderr  <to>  Null      <use>  2>Nul
stderr  <to>  stdout    <use>  2>&1 
stderr  <to>  File.Log  <use>  2>File.Log

stdout  <to>  Null      <use>  >Nul
stdout  <to>  Null      <use> 1>Nul
stdout  <to>  File.Log  <use>  >File.Log
stdout  <to>  File.Log  <use> 1>File.Log

Redirection stdout and stderr to File.Log:
2>&1  YourCommandHere   >File.Log
2>&1  YourCommandHere  1>File.Log
```

---

```bat
Set IP address to USB Ethernet : 
Enter the System IP address [127.*.*.*]:               //user input [stdin]
Enter the System Subnet Mask [Default: 255.255.255.0]: //user input [stdin]
Enter the System Default Gateway [127.*.*.*]:          //user input [stdin]
Avaliable Ethernet Interface:
Admin State.    State         Type            Interface Name
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Enable          Conected      Dedicaed        Wi-Fi
    
Type the Ethernet Interface Name:                      //user input [stdin]
```

---

**Additional resources:**

- [`If /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html)
- [`Del /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/del.html)
- [`FindSTR /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)
- [`For /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)
- [Conditional Execution](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)

  - [`||`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html) and [`&&`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)
- [Commands Redirection](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)

  - `|`, `<`, `>`, `2>`, etc.
- [How does the Windows Command Interpreter [`cmd.exe`] Parse Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4094699/6819406)